# How to retrieve ETF constituents(holdings) weightings information by Bloomberg API?

Tags: python, bloomberg, pdblp

How to retrieve ETF constituents(holdings) weightings information by **bloomberg API**?

**xbbg  or pdblp  **

below is for Index and it's working

```
    import pdblp
    con = pdblp.Bcon()
    con.start()
    con.bulkref('BCOM Index','INDEX_MWEIGHT')
```

but, not working ro ETF like 'IVV US Equity' .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Mm5.png)

the output information is what i want

Comment: Last time I asked (a year ago or so), it was not possible to retrieve ETF holdings via the API. Maybe it's changed, you should ask the help desk.

Comment: I've only managed to get this data using `BQL`, which can be a struggle to achieve via Python.